can't pass acme challenge with certbot in docker
i'm trying to pass acme challenge to get cert with docker
docker run --rm -it --name certbot --network=host -v "/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" -v "/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" certbot/certbot -v --agree-tos -d #mysn#.sn.mynetname.net --http-01-port 80 certonly
server is aviable on http://#mysn#.sn.mynetname.net
but challenge fail on timeout I guess... what I'm doing wrong?
notice:
my server is behind nat, so I'm exposing port via ssh tunnel to static address like
ssh -vTNR 0.0.0.0:80:0.0.0.0:80 myuser@mynetname.net
I'm trying to get ssl certs
